# Where is the JSON file coming from?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking at a source code and I get the hold of the author of it. In the code you can do a search for a track and it'll return a list with names and ids for the track but I can't figure where it's getting the json file from. I have attached the code below.

```
function searchForTrack() {
    console.log("search for a track");
    var q = $("#search-text").val();
    console.log(q);

    if (q.length > 0) {
        var url = 'search'
        $.getJSON(url, { q:q, results:30}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i].id = data[i].trid;
            }
            listTracks('#search-list', data);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the search box:

```
<div id='search-form'> 
                Search for a track <input id="search-text" type="text"> <button id="search"> Search </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Read the code. It's getting the file from the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var url = 'search'
    $.getJSON(url,
```

The URL is `search` (which a query string created from the data in the second argument) which will be computed relative to the URL of the document the script is running in.

The Net tab of your browser's developer tools will show you the absolute URL being requested.